# ¿Por qué un "hola mundo" en Rust pesa tanto en comparación a un "hola mundo" escrito en C?

Tags: c, rust

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Rust, vengo de haber estudiado algo de C, y había leído que Rust tenia un rendimiento similar en C, por lo que, naturalmente me puse a compararlos y me di cuenta de que en el mismo programa escrito en ambos lenguajes hay una diferencia de tamaño demasiado grande (a mi parecer) donde un programa un rust es 183 veces mas grande que uno escrito en C, ¿Me podrian explicar porque pasa esto?.

Posdata: Mi intención con esta pregunta no es comparar ni decir cual es el mejor, esta pregunta es solo curiosidad.

[image: Programas compilados en C y en Rust][image: Programa escrito en C][image: Programa escrito en Rust]

Comment: rust es un lenguaje compilado o interpretado?

Comment: Rust es un lenguaje compilado

Comment: Interesante pregunta. Si sabes algo de inglés, puedes leer las varias respuestas acá [Why are Rust executables so huge?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29008127/8838721). Hay una que hace la comparación con C tal y como la planteas.

Comment: El código debe ir en formato texto y no en imagen. Haz clic en [edit] y cambia lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: 1. No pegues pantallazos con código. Pega el código como tal. Aplica igual para los tamaños.
2. No estás comparando más que el tamaño del archivo que contiene el código fuente. C se guarda en archivos de texto simples. Resulta obvio que rust no (o al menos no con el IDE o editor que estás usando); 2.1 Apostaría a que si comparas un programa con 20,000 líneas, rust no seguirá siendo 183 veces más grande que C, diría que la relación va a _mejorar_. 3 El tamaño del código fuente es irrelevante a la hora de medir la eficiencia de un programa en ejecución.

Comment: @jachguate está comparando los ejecutables, no el código fuente. Si 3 líneas de código se llevaran 3.58 Mb sería preocupante esa codificación.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Acabo de ver el articulo en ingles, y se explica claramente la pregunta que acabo de hacer, Muchas gracias

Comment: La respuesta es obvia, al menos para mi: Rust !== C.

Comment: Vamos a ver si estamos en lo que estamos. ¿ Como se compilaron ambos programas ? ¿ Con información de depuración o sin ella ? ¿ Con optimizaciones de tamaño o sin ellas ? ¿ Se enlazaron de forma dinámica o estática ? Si se enlazó estático ... ¿ la librería enlazada estaba compilada con información de depuración ? ¿ Compilada con optimización de tamaño ? Este tipo de preguntas habría que cerrarlas directamente.

Comment: @Arslong-Vitabrevis Me da la impresion que es por las liberirias estandar de rust, https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/index.html.